# How to add color palette to BITMAPINFO

Tags: c++, image, bmp, grayscale

I have a function which creates a `bmp` file and writes the file header, the info header, and the actual pixel data respectively. Here it is:

```
bool SaveBMP(BYTE* Buffer, int width, int height, long paddedsize, LPCTSTR bmpfile)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER info;

    memset(&bmfh, 0, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42;       // 0x4d42 = 'BM'
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmfh.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + paddedsize;
    bmfh.bfOffBits = 0x36;      // number of bytes to start of bitmap bits

    info.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    info.biWidth = width;
    info.biHeight = height;
    info.biPlanes = 1;          
    info.biBitCount = 8;        
    info.biCompression = 0;
    info.biSizeImage = 0;       
    info.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;   
    info.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    info.biClrUsed = 256;       
    info.biClrImportant = 0;    

    HANDLE file = CreateFile(bmpfile, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                             NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // write file header
    unsigned long bwritten;
    if (WriteFile(file, &bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &bwritten, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    // write infoheader
    if (WriteFile(file, &info, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &bwritten, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    // write image data
    if (WriteFile(file, Buffer, paddedsize, &bwritten, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    // and close file
    CloseHandle(file);

    return true;
}
```

However, I understand that I have to provide a color palette for 8bit grayscale images like in the following code.

```
BITMAPINFO* pbmi

for (int i = 0; i<256; i++)
{
    pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = i;
    pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = i;
    pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = i;
    pbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = 0;
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to connect my `BITMAPINFOHEADER` to the `BITMAPINFO`.

And is there a way to use `CreateDIBSection` function with my current code?

Comment: When you say that it writes the "actual pixel data", what exactly do you mean by this? More specifically, in what format is the data written to disk? Is it 24bit data i.e width x height x 3, (which requires indexing). Or is it already 8bit data i.e width x height x 1? In either case, the palette data immediately follows the BITMAPINFOHEADER. (Have a look at the BITMAPINFO struct - it contains both, sort-of - I'll leave you to research that. Basically, the bmiColors array can be used to access more than 1 rgbquad. Search "variable length struct member c")

Comment: There's nothing to "connect". You just write the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` right after the `BITMAPFILHEADER`, and then the palette data after that. Make sure that you adjust `bfOffBits` and `biSize` accordingly (e.g. a 256 color palette would mean that both of those field need to be offset by 1024).

Comment: @Michael is right. Ignore `BITMAPINFO` completely and write the palette as a separate entity. Since it only reserves space for one color entry, it's just going to get you into trouble if you try to use it.

Comment: @enhzflep It is a 8bpp grayscale image. So yeah, 8 bit data. Actually I would like to ask, do I really need a color palette for 8 bit grayscale?

Comment: @Michael @enhzflep By 1024 do you mean 128 bytes? How do I write the palette data myself? (I'm talking about the case that I don't use `BITMAPINFO` at all.) I would be glad if you could post this as an answer with some example code.

Comment: No, 1024. 256 colors * sizeof(RGBQUAD) == 1024. As far as writing the data goes; as I mentioned before, first you write the `BITMAPFILEHEADER` struct, then the `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, then the palette data (the `RGBQUAD`s).

Comment: @Michael Thanks, I got it working now. BTW, it turns out that you shoud increase `bfOffBits` and `bfSize` by 1024 but not touch `biSize`. I think the color palette is considered seperately from the `BITMAPINFOHEADER`.

Comment: @Michael One last question :) We have `2^8 = 256` colors because it's a 8bpp image right? What if the image was 16bpp, would we have `2^16` colors then?

Comment: No. For a 16-bit BMP you'd set `biCompression = BI_BITFIELDS`, and instead of a palette you'd write three 32-bit bitmasks that indicate how to extract the red, green and blue components of each 16-bit pixel. For RGB565 those bitmasks would be `0xF800, 0x07E0, 0x001F` (those are 4 bytes each, little-endian, but the top 16 bits of each are all zeroes. so `bfSize` and `bfOffBits` both increase by 3*4 == 12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the function and didn't use `BITMAPINFO` at all. I used `RGBQUAD` to write the color palette instead. Here's the solution:

```
bool SaveBMP(BYTE* Buffer, int width, int height, long paddedsize, LPCTSTR bmpfile)
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_COLORS = 256;
    const int COLOR_PALETTE_SIZE = NUMBER_OF_COLORS * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
    const int HEADER_OFFSET = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + COLOR_PALETTE_SIZE;
    const int TOTAL_FILE_SIZE = HEADER_OFFSET + paddedsize;

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER info;
    RGBQUAD quad[NUMBER_OF_COLORS];
    memset(&bmfh, 0, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    // create the color palette
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLORS; i++)
    {
        quad[i].rgbBlue = i;
        quad[i].rgbGreen = i;
        quad[i].rgbRed = i;
        quad[i].rgbReserved = 0;
    }

    // fill the fileheader
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42;           // 0x4d42 = 'BM'
    bmfh.bfSize = TOTAL_FILE_SIZE;  // Total file size
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;           // UNUSED
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;           // UNUSED
    bmfh.bfOffBits = HEADER_OFFSET; // Offset to start of pixel data

    // fill the infoheader
    info.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); // Header size (Must be at least 40)
    info.biWidth = width;                   // Image width
    info.biHeight = -height;                // Image height
    info.biPlanes = 1;                      // MUST BE 1
    info.biBitCount = 8;                    // Bits per pixel (1, 4, 8, 16, 24 or 32)
    info.biCompression = 0;                 // Compression type (BI_RGB = 0, BI_RLE8 = 1, BI_RLE4 = 2 or BI_BITFIELDS = 3)
    info.biSizeImage = height * width;      // Image size (May be 0 if not compressed)
    info.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;               // Preferred resolution in pixels per meter
    info.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;               // Preferred resolution in pixels per meter
    info.biClrUsed = NUMBER_OF_COLORS;      // Number of entries in the color map that are actually used
    info.biClrImportant = 0;                // Number of significant colors (All colors = 0)

    // open the file to write to 
    HANDLE file = CreateFile(bmpfile, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    // write file header
    unsigned long bwritten;
    if (WriteFile(file, &bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &bwritten, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    // write info header
    if (WriteFile(file, &info, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &bwritten, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    // write palette
    if (WriteFile(file, quad, COLOR_PALETTE_SIZE, &bwritten, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    // write image data
    if (WriteFile(file, Buffer, paddedsize, &bwritten, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    // close file
    CloseHandle(file);
    return true;
}
```