# Bitmap 8bit Grayscale Image In C

Tags: c, bitmap, grayscale

I am trying to create a bitmap grayscale image in C. The Problem is bits per pixel if i set it to 24 => 3 bytes it works but give me color image. I want to set it 8 => 1 byte so it produce grayscale image.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
    char bitmap[1000];
    FILE *bp;

    // -- FILE HEADER -- //

   // bitmap signature
   bitmap[0] = 0x42; // B
   bitmap[1] = 0x4d; // M

   // file size
   bitmap[2] = 0x86; // 40 + 14 + 12 (134-66) = 68
   bitmap[3] = 0;
   bitmap[4] = 0;
   bitmap[5] = 0;

   // reserved field (in hex. 00 00 00 00)
   for (int i = 6; i < 10; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    bitmap[10] = 54; // 54-36

   // offset of pixel data inside the image
   for (int i = 11; i < 14; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // -- BITMAP HEADER -- //

    // header size
    bitmap[14] = 0x28; // 40
    for (int i = 15; i < 18; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // width of the image
    bitmap[18] = 4; // 5
    for (int i = 19; i < 22; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // height of the image
    bitmap[22] = 1; // 5
    for (int i = 23; i < 26; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // reserved field
    bitmap[26] = 1;
    bitmap[27] = 0;

    // number of bits per pixel
    bitmap[28] = 24; // 3 byte 24
    bitmap[29] = 0;

    // compression method (no compression here)
    for (int i = 30; i < 34; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // size of pixel data
    bitmap[34] = 24; // 12 bits => 4 pixels 80
    bitmap[35] = 0;
    bitmap[36] = 0;
    bitmap[37] = 0;

    // horizontal resolution of the image - pixels per meter (2835)
    bitmap[38] = 0;
    bitmap[39] = 0;
    bitmap[40] = 0xC4; //48
    bitmap[41] = 0x0E; //177

    // vertical resolution of the image - pixels per meter (2835)
    bitmap[42] = 0;
    bitmap[43] = 0;
    bitmap[44] = 0xC4;
    bitmap[45] = 0x0E;

    // color pallette information
    for (int i = 46; i < 48; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // color pallette information
    for (int i = 48; i < 50; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // number of important colors
    for (int i = 50; i < 52; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // number of important colors
    for (int i = 52; i < 54; i++) bitmap[i] = 0;

    // -- PIXEL DATA -- //
    for (int i = 54; i < 134; i++){
    if ( i %2 == 0)
        bitmap[i] = 0xFF;
    else bitmap[i] = 0;
    }
    /*bitmap[54] =1; bitmap[55] = 1; bitmap[56] = 0;
    bitmap[57] = 1; bitmap[58] = 1; bitmap[59] = 0;
    bitmap[60] = 1; bitmap[61] = 1; bitmap[62] = 0;
    bitmap[63] = 1; bitmap[64] = 1; bitmap[65] = 0;*/

    bp = fopen("e://binary.bmp", "wb");
    for (int i = 0; i < 134; i++) {
        fprintf(bp, "%c", bitmap[i]);
    }
    fclose(bp);

}
```

Comment: You are really coding this the hard way. The normal way is to fill a BITMAPINFO structure and write it in a single go.

Comment: just make all colors (rgb) the same...

Comment: Another thing how can i increase the image height and width! If i change the width from 4 to anyother number image doesn't work same with the height!

Comment: Who downvoted the question?

Answer (score 0):

Set BitsPerPixel= 8 and let the header be followed by 256 RGBQUAD entries defining a gray ramp.

Comment: When i set bitsperpixel to 8 it doesn't work! This code is showing color bitmap. So somehow it bitperpixel = 8 works i guess we don't need to add 256 colors.

Comment: @ahsanic Set BitsPerPixel= 8 and let the header be followed by 256 RGBQUAD entries defining a gray ramp.

Comment: how to add 256 rgbquad entries after the table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707407/how-to-add-color-palette-to-bitmapinfo